# Google Extension: Throws error while sending data from webpage to extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

***This error keep popping up when I try to send data from the webpage to the extension. The data that was send clearly not arrive to its destination***

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

My simple setup:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Extensions</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Service-Worker:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (sender.url === blocklistedWebsite)
        return;  // don't allow this web page access
      if (request.openUrlInEditor)
        openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
    });
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "TestExtension",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["https://twitter.com/home", "https://127.0.0.1:7236/"],
    "ids": ["abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc"]
  },
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
      }
  }
```

**Webpage**

```
window.sendStateToExtension = () => {
        // The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
        var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

        // Make a simple request:
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, { openUrlInEditor: "www.google.com" },
            function (response) {
                if (!response.success)
                    handleError(url);
            });
}

function getStoreState() {
   // Implemntation...
}
```

Comment: Remove `:7236` and add `*` at the end, replace `home` with `*`, remove the entire "ids" line. Also, usually localhost is http not https.

Comment: I used this:

"matches": ["https://localhost/*", "https://127.0.0.1/*", "http://localhost/*", "http://127.0.0.1/*", "https://*/*"]

and other combinations. it still not working.

my website sits on https://localhost:7236/

Comment: Your `*` is in the wrong place, try `*://localhost/*` and `*://127.0.0.1/*` which will match both http and https.